# ansible Jinja2 JSON loop last elements

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Im trying to produce a JSON file from a Jinja2 template using variables passed from Ansible. As far as I know there are no modules that help me here (stand to be corrected?).

Im stuck on the last loop

```
{
  "items": [
    {% for host in hostvars %}
    {"apiversion": "v1",
    "lastrunupdate": "{{ hostvars[host]['date'] }}",
    "hostname": "null",
    "hostip": "{{ hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname'] }}",
    "whoami": "{{ hostvars[host]['whoamiraw'] }}",
    "serialnumber": "{{ hostvars[host]['serial'] }}",
    "version": "{{ hostvars[host]['version'] }}",
    "ipaddress": "{{hostvars[host]['ipaddressraw'] }}",
    "users": [
        {% for hosts in hostvars[host]['listofusersraw'] %}

         {"user":"{{ listofusersraw[loop.index0].split(':')[0] }}" } {% if not loop.last %},{%else%}]},{% endif %}{% endfor %} 



      {% endfor %}
}
]
}
```

The issue is that the last loop adds `},` to the end of the json list.

Comment: "*thoughts please*" ー here's a thought: you should produce [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first by removing unnecessary code from what you posted (is `"hostname": "null",` relevant to the problem?), then by adding missing bits (so others don't have to recreate what you omitted), and finally by clearly specifying what is your expectation and what is the actual result.　・　For example your words "*the last loop ads the }*" are meaningless without context: Is it what you intended? Is it what you wanted to prevent (and how?), but did not work? Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some extra characters in your jinja2. Remove the else when adding the comma:

```
{

    "items": [
                {% for host in hostvars %}
                    {"apiversion": "v1",
                    "lastrunupdate": "{{ hostvars[host]['date'] }}",
                    "hostname": "null",
                    "hostip": "{{ hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname'] }}",
                    "whoami": "{{ hostvars[host]['whoamiraw'] }}",
                    "serialnumber": "{{ hostvars[host]['serial'] }}",
                    "version": "{{ hostvars[host]['version'] }}",
                    "ipaddress": "{{hostvars[host]['ipaddressraw'] }}",
                    "users": [

                        {% for hosts in hostvars[host]['listofusersraw'] %}

                            {"user": "{{ listofusersraw[loop.index0].split(':')[0] }}" }

                            {% if not loop.last %}
                              ,
                            {% endif %}

                        {% endfor %}
                            ]
                {% endfor %}
                    }
            ]
}
```

> **Note:** I have splitted it to be more readable.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for the poor post originally, was a long day!